# Как заполнить dataTable по запросу SQLite?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Есть метод, который получает список сотрудников и заполняет List employeesList. Как переделать код метода, чтобы заполнялся не лист а dataTable?

```
private void GetEmployees()
 {
     employeesList.Clear();

     string query = "SELECT p.Id, p.Lastname, p.Firstname, p.Surname, (SELECT Post FROM Posts WHERE e.PostId = Id), e.PersonnelNumber, p.DateOfBirth, e.IsActive " +
                    "FROM Employees e " +
                    "INNER JOIN Persons p " +
                    "ON p.Id = e.PersonId " +
                    "ORDER BY p.Lastname";

     try
     {
         command = DataBase.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = query;

         DataBase.OpenConnection();
         reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             employeesList.Add(new ViewEmployeesModel
             {
                 Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                 Lastname = reader.GetString(1),
                 Firstname = reader.GetString(2),
                 Surname = reader.GetString(3),
                 Post = reader.GetString(4),
                 PersonnelNumber = reader.GetInt32(5),
                 DateOfBirth = reader.GetString(6),
                 IsActive = reader.GetString(7) == "1" ? "действующий" : "уволен"
             });
         }
         reader.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось загрузить список сотрудников :" +
                         $"\n\"{ex.Message}\"\nОбратитесь к системному администратору для устранения ошибки.",
                         "Ошибка при работе с Базой Данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
     }

     DataBase.CloseConnection();
 }
```

Таблица в WinForms сейчас заполняется из источника List employeesTable.DataSource = employeesList
Но нужно, чтобы таблица заполнялась из dataTable.

Comment: Для фильтрации и сортировки нужно использовать DataView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-8.0

Comment: Конечно офтоп сообщение, извините, но вот смотрю я на этот код, и прям больно на душе. Неужели вот прям суровое требование, использовать именно древний ADO.NET? В современном мире, это как не знаю, вспахивать поле запрягая лошадей, а не использовать трактор и другую технику. Вот весь ваш код, при использовании современных вещей по типу EF, преобразуется в простое `var result = db.Where(x=>x.PostId == Id).OrderBy(x=>x.Lastname);`, одна строка, без каких либо конвертов, создания объектов и даже без написания SQL вручную... Не, конечно для познания SQL, мб и полезно, но все же, уверены?)